# User Control refactoring

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, ascx

This is a performance issue and also a refactoring problem.

I have a .NET user control (UCA.ascx)... which in turn uses 5 other User Controls internally.
Each of these user controls run into greater than 2000 lines of code.

The web page loads UCA.ascx first ... then the other 5 user controls are loaded dynamically based on actions in UCA.ascx.
The code-behind of of these user controls use DTOs and have business logic in them.

The main problem is to resolve the long loading time and delayed operational time (due to postbacks). To resolve this issue, I would need to make sense of the code first.

- So, is there guidance on what should be and what should NOT be in the
  user-control code-behind codebase?
- Is there a tool-driven or easier way to refactor large, unwieldy user controls?

Comment: Particularly with such large amounts of code you shouldn't be just looking around for things that look bad and fixing them.  Chances are this will occupy you for quite some time before you even start to address the real problems.  You need to profile the code to see where its spending its time and focus on optimizing *that*.

Answer (score 1):

- Optimally, there should be *no* business logic or data access logic in your presentation layer at all. The code in your presentation layer should consist only of code to retrieve business objects and bind them to the appropriate controls on the page.
- ReSharper has some built-in refactoring tools where you can extract methods from your codebase, but generally speaking, refactoring like this is delicate and should be approached very carefully, with forethought to how you're approaching the redesign.

As you refactor, try to keep [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles in mind and add unit tests wherever it's feasible.